# How to use a nested loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe (called NP) where each column (between 2 and 29 - these are countries) has time series data, so 1st column is for years. I would like to find for each column the year in which the value is closest to a set of values and create a data frame (or matrix?) out of that.

The code below works for one single value (200).

```
del <- vector()
for (i in seq_along(NP[,2:29])) {
  del[i] <- which.min(abs(NP[,2:29][[i]] - 200))
}
del
NP$Year[del]
 [1] 1970 1995 1980 1970 1970 1992 1980 1994 1980 1970 1997 1970 1980 1998 1995 1970
[17] 1992 1990 1970 1970 1995 1991 2008 1980 1996 1970 1970 1970
```

What I would like to have is instead of just one single value 200 the same thing but for a sequence of values (X). I tried this:

```
X = seq(from=200, to=700, by=50)
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow = 11, ncol = 28)
for (i in seq_along(X)) {
  for (j in seq_along(NP[,2:29])){
    mymatrix[i,j] <- which.min(abs(NP[,2:29][[j]]) - i)
  }
}
```

The matrix does not give the right values, though. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is my dataframe:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mwi4480ewaahm0/NP.xlsx?dl=0

What I would like to have as an and result: a separate dataframe where columns would be countries and rows would be values ranging from 200 to 700, and entries would be years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter version double-loop with `sapply`. We loop over values of `X` and all columns of `NP` and get minimum index of absolute values between them.

```
sapply(X, function(x) sapply(NP[2:29], function(y) which.min(abs(y - x))))


#               [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#Belgium           1    1    2    2    5   12   28   28   28    28    28
#Bulgaria          8   13   16   23   26   28   28   28   28    28    28
#Czech Republic    2    5    8   14   19   26   28   28   28    28    28
#Denmark           1    2    4   15   25   28   28   28   28    28    28
#Germany           1    1    2    2   10   10    9   28   28    28    28
#Estonia           5    7   14   17   20   25   27   28   28    28    28
#Ireland           2    6    9   13   18   21   21   21   21    21    21
#.....
```

If you want to find out the years

```
sapply(X, function(x) sapply(NP[2:29], function(y) NP$Year[which.min(abs(y - x))]))


#               [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#Belgium        1970 1970 1980 1980 1992 1999 2015 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Bulgaria       1995 2000 2003 2010 2013 2015 2015 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Czech Republic 1980 1992 1995 2001 2006 2013 2015 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Denmark        1970 1980 1991 2002 2012 2015 2015 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Germany        1970 1970 1980 1980 1997 1997 1996 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Estonia        1992 1994 2001 2004 2007 2012 2014 2015 2015  2015  2015
#Ireland        1980 1993 1996 2000 2005 2008 2008 2008 2008  2008  2008
#......
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `i in seq_along(X)` which produces in your case a sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11`, but you want to subtract the value of `X` within your inner loop. You have to adjust your code to

```
X = seq(from=200, to=700, by=50)
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow = 11, ncol = 28)
for (i in seq_along(X)) {
  for (j in seq_along(NP[,2:29])){
    mymatrix[i,j] <- which.min(abs(NP[,2:29][[j]]) - X[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work. I uploaded the dataframe to my dropbox.